# Are the three laws of motion (which is attributted to Sir Isaac Newton) really present in the Vaisheshika Sutras of Kanada?

Tags: identification-request, science, vaisheshika, vaisheshika-sutra, kanada

Certain web articles such as [this one](http://mailonnews.com/manchester-university-research-confirms-this-is-how-isaac-newton-stole-concept-of-gravity-from-a-hindu-gurukul-in-india/), over the past few months have been claiming that the [three laws of motion](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/newton.html) which are attributed to the famous British scientist Sir Isaac Newton, **were actually mentioned earlier in the Vaishesika Sutras of Kanada**! These articles have also been claiming **that some leading professors of Manchester University have themselves confirmed this** (though I couldn't verify this). In addition to this, the leading Right-wing intellectual, Subramanian Swamy has supported these claims on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/swamy39/status/933099418026311682?lang=en):

> Manchester Univ. Confirms: This is How Isaac Newton Stole Concept of Gravity from a Hindu Gurukul http://mailonnews.com/2017/09/19/manchester-university-research-confirms-this-is-how-isaac-newton-stole-concept-of-gravity-from-a-hindu-gurukul-in-india/ … via @
>
> (2:26 PM - 21 Nov 2017)

So the questions that naturally arise are:

- Has the Manchester University really confirmed that Kanada discovered the laws of motion before Newton?
- Do the Vaisheshika Sutras of Kanada truly mention these three laws of motion?

Comment: Closely related: [What do our scriptures say about Parmanu (Atom) and Maharshi Kanad?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10780/277) - answer to that question mention it. Another realted question: [Is there any mention of Newton's law of motions in Hindu scriptures? \[closed\]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19534/277)